# pysnmp on raspberry pi

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi3, pysnmp

I have just installed pysnmp on my rpi, quick check with snmplab's agent side script i got error (module missing in library)

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python implementing-scalar-mib-objects.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "implementing-scalar-mib-objects.py", line 20, in module
>
> from pysnmp.entity import engine, config.
>
> ImportError: No module named pysnmp.entity

Here are my installed packages: 
pyasn1 (0.4.4),
pycrypto (2.6.1),
pycryptodomex (3.6.6),
pygobject (3.22.0),
pysmi (0.3.1),
pysnmp (4.4.6)

Note : I tried running the same script on other linux machine (on my laptop, debian 9) it run  well. 
what i've done wrong on my raspberry pysnmp setup ?

Edit : 
last night i've revisited the problem, seems above symptom was caused by sudo prefix. For some reason, pysnmp on rpi platform has problem with the sudo prefix command. It couldn't locate the modules folder.
my workaround was reinstalled the pysnmp in global environment : sudo pip install pysnmp. 
Anyone can advise better solution ?

regards

Suryo